# Saving several PDFs at once in the Google Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, pdf

I have a Google Chrome window that contains a couple of tabs, some of which being PDFs. Is any way to save all those PDFs at once to a given folder?

I use Google Chrome on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to save all PDFs opened in tabs in a Google Chrome window at once to a given folder.